# calling a variable in PHP while loop

Tags: php

i have a website structure as follow

```
<div id="title">
<h1> //call $title here after executing loop </h1>
</div>
<?php 
   ...
     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { $title = $row['title']; ?>

<h2> this is the <?php echo $title;?> </h2>
<?php } ?>
```

is there a way i could still use or call the `$title` variable on an html element on top of the while loop statement?

whenever i call it above the while loop i get errors  like `Undefined variable: id..`

edit: change id into 'title' instead

Comment: Since $id will have different values on each iteration, what do you want to echo outside the while loop exactly?

Comment: instead of use the value before it is set ,you may try other methods such as javascript ,to set the <h1>value after the dom tree is loaded

Comment: get the $id data using session otherwise you are unable to get the $id outside of for loop.

Comment: Are you using ```while()``` just to retrieve one row?

Comment: @ChinmaySahu okay, that make sense. i could put it on session and use it.. thanks for the idea

Comment: @ChinmaySahu He can get variable after loop, but he can't get it before. Even from session.

Answer (score 2):

PHP will read code line by line so variable can't be used before declaration.

Only one option is to move loop above your div, get html from loop inside variable and print it later.

I think that you've got only one row in that loop so use this code instead.

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$title = $row['title'];
echo '<h2> this is the '.$title.' </h2>';
```

Comment: yes, this is what i thought too.. but still dared to ask if (ever) theres a way to call the variable

Comment: @user1933824 There is no variable when you want to call it :) But why do you want to get it from loop and which one? First, last or maybe something from the middle?

Comment: i wanted to get the value from a loop and insert it somewhere on my `<head>` tag, but the loop declaration is located in `<body>`. it will be alot of work if i move the while loop few divs up.

Comment: @user1933824 But which row from loop do you want to get?

Comment: the `['title'] row from my loop. a comment above suggested i could just put the variable in the session. and then call the session. would that work?

Comment: @user1933824 No, it will not work. How many times your loop executes?

Comment: Putting it into a while means you have more than one `$row['title']`. If you have only one - you don't need loop

Comment: oh, now i get your question. im actually looping the titles and the ID associated with the title. i want to get the ID of the recent entry title and use that ID for other purposes

Comment: @user1933824 Ok, so there is no option for you, just moving loop before first use of variable from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only retrieving a single row, you don't need the loop:

```
<?php
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$title = $row['title'];
?>

<div id="title">
    <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
</div>
```